Curl of a vector field belongs to the tangent space of a manifold
While studying Analysis on Manifolds in Elon Lages book, in the Chapter of Stokes Theorem there was this problem:
Let U $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ be a open set and consider $F: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ a smooth vector field, and let $M \subseteq U$ be a smooth manifold such that $F(p) = 0$ for every $p \in M$. Show that for every $p \in M$, $\nabla\times F(p) \in T_pM$
I couldn't solve this problem, and actually my only idea was trying to prove that $\nabla\times F(p)$ could be seen was a derivation for M, so I would have to prove it satisfies the Leibniz Rule. And perhaps the relation of this with Stokes Theorem is that you can see this vector field as a 1-form on $U$ and then it's curl it's just the derivative, so I could try using Stokes, but no further progress has been made.

Indeed, let $F$ correspond in the usual way to a $1$-form $\omega$. Then $\text{curl}\,F$ corresponds to (the Hodge star of) $d\omega$. If the restriction of $d\omega$ to $M$ is not everywhere zero, choose a little region $\Sigma\subset M$ on which $d\omega$ never vanishes. Then $\int_\Sigma d\omega\ne 0$  (why?), and yet $\int_{\partial\Sigma}\omega=0$. Oops.
(Remember that $d\omega = (\text{curl}\,F\cdot n)\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the area $2$-form on $\Sigma\subset M$. We assume $\Sigma$ is chosen small enough to be oriented, even if $M$ might happen not to be orientable.)
